# Using health points on my Enemies

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

Currently building a SHMUP for a school project, I am fairly new to OOP and moreoever as3 and having troubles using class Inheritance.

I'm using those classes :

```
<ul>
    <li>ShootPlayer</li>
    <li>Enemies</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Enemy0</li>
        <li>Enemy1</li>
        <li>Enemy2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

My goal is to add health points to my enemies. The idea was basically to create a property named enemyHealth:int, and each time Player hits the enemy,  enemyHealth -= 1;, when enemyHealth = 0, removeChild this enemy, splice arrays etc...

I'm not sure how to put this up for now. Here is what I've done on Enemies class.``

```
public function enemiesHealth(pHealth:int):void {
    var enemyHealth:int = pHealth;
    enemyHealth -= 1;
}
```

And I wanted to override this function on each of my enemy. For example Enemy0

```
override public function enemiesHealth():void {
     super.enemiesHealth(3);
}
```

And run the function on my ShootPlayer doAction

```
for (var i:int = Enemies.enemies.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {

    if (CollisionManager.hasCollision(box, Enemies.enemies[i]  )) {
        Enemies.enemiesHealth();
        trace(Enemies.enemyHealth);
        parent.removeChild(Enemies.enemies[i]);
        destroy();
        shootsPlayer.splice(shootsPlayer.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
}
```

But well, since I'm not writing anything into the parenthesis, that basically doesnt make any sense.

Getting error Type 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method enemiesHealth through a reference with static type

Any help on how to put this up?

Many thanks

Comment: You lack a clear problem statement.  What is or isn't happening? Or what isn't making sense to you exactly?

Comment: Well im Getting error Type 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method enemiesHealth through a reference with static type
But I know the way I'm trying to make it work insnt the proper way. I basically do not know how I should proceed to create the Hp system.

Comment: That's because `Enemies` is the class,  not an instance of a class.  You need to do `Enemies.enemies[i].enemiesHealth();`  This assumes that `enemies` is a static var in your Enemies class (you would be getting a different error if that were not the case)

Answer (score 0):

enemiesHealth is a member function and it should be called on an instance variable. You are calling that method like if it is static method.

Although I couldn't clearly understand your code (due naming confusions), you can try

```
Enemies.enemies[i].enemiesHealth();
```